# How do i write a failing test to add another branch in an if statement without external state

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

With this code:

```
Public class Processor {
  Public Processor(Ifoo colloborator, Ibar otherCollobotator)
  Public void Process() {
// if (newFoo)
// new action
  If (foo) 
    this.colloborator.doSomething();
  If (bar)
    this.colloborator.doSomethingElse();
  Else     this.otherColloborator.doSomethingCompletelyDiffetent();
}
```

I want to add a another branch at the top to do something else (commented out).  I know one way to do it, it involves verifying, or not, calls on colloborators using an appropriate mock/spy.
And to be clear I have done this already, succesfully and with TDD 'without' introducing another colloborator.

How would you tackle this? From a test first perspective?

I think eventually it could be refactored with something called pluggable object/adapter.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  How did you test-drive the code to this point?  With checks on mock collaborators?  When you mention collapsing if/else, it sounds like you're asking about refactoring the production code, not writing test code.

Comment: Exactly as you say.  I wondered whether there was another way.   Id write a test or tests and then refactor no probs with that

Comment: @brumScouse sorry, I have write this based on misunderstanding the question more like "how can I write multiple conditions where each is invoking other method". My bad

Comment: Hi @tatra. No my fault, Actually i think my question is misleading, i will reword it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your new action also calls the collaborator, you can mock it out.

Example with RhinoMocks:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
  //Arrange
  ICollaborator mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICollaborator>();
  Processor myProc = new Processor(mock, ...);

  //Act
  myProc.Process();

  //Assert
  mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.MethodToBeCalled);
}
```

This will of course fail if you do not change your Process method.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you said, you'd need to check that when condition is true, `new action` is called, and when condition is false, then `new action is not called`. So, first we'd define our new interface:

```
public interface INewAction
{
    void NewAction();
}
```

Then, we modify our processor (note that we DID NOT yet add the new if branch):

```
public class Processor {
private readonly INewAction _newAction;
  public Processor(Ifoo colloborator, Ibar otherCollobotator, INewAction newAction)
{
// whatever we had before
_newAction = newAction;
}
  public void Process() {
  if (foo) 
    this.colloborator.doSomething();
  of (bar)
    this.colloborator.doSomethingElse();
  else     this.otherColloborator.doSomethingCompletelyDiffetent();
}
```

Now we write our test cases:

```
[TestClass]
public class ProcessorTests
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void Process_GivenNewFoo_CallsNewAction()
  {
    // arrange 'newfoo' condition

    // mockout our processor, e.g.
    var mockNewAction = new Mock<INewAction>(); // this is Moq, for others use appropriate syntax, e.g. Substitute.For<INewAction>() for NSubstitute etc.

    mockNewAction.Setup(x => x.NewAction()).Verifiable();
    var target = new Processor(null, null, mockNewAction.Object);

    target.Process();

    mockNewAction.Verify(x => x.NewAction(), Times.Once);
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void Process_GivenNewFoo_False_DoesNotCallNewAction()
  {
    // arrange 'newfoo' condition to be false

    // mockout our processor, e.g.
    var mockNewAction = new Mock<INewAction>(); // this is Moq, for others use appropriate syntax, e.g. Substitute.For<INewAction>() for NSubstitute etc.

    mockNewAction.Setup(x => x.NewAction()).Verifiable();
    var target = new Processor(null, null, mockNewAction.Object);

    target.Process();

    mockNewAction.Verify(x => x.NewAction(), Times.Never);
  }
}
```

When we run them, the second test will pass -> well, this is expected, because essentially the behaviour is `if NOT newfoo then don't call it`. But the first test WILL fails (as is the TDD approach).

And now we modify the Processor again, just the `Process()` method:

```
  public void Process() {
    if(newFoo)
    {
      _newAction.NewAction();
    }
  if (foo) 
    this.colloborator.doSomething();
  of (bar)
    this.colloborator.doSomethingElse();
  else     this.otherColloborator.doSomethingCompletelyDiffetent();
}
```

At this point both the tests pass and we completed the TDD cycle.

Comment: Hi zaitsman,  yeah this approach is definitely a goer.  However one small tweak Id make would be to add the test first.   We can drive the design of the code in exactly the way we want it to be used.  So we would write our failing test,  with the a mock of the interface, set up our expecations, have them fail and then fill in the code to meet our expectations.

Comment: This is exactly what i did. The test DOES fail first, if you read carefully. It's just that for an IF condition you need at least two tests (true/false) and because your behaviour is simplistic, it is impossible to make one fail, but the other will.

Comment: "So, first we'd define our new interface" -  No you defined an interface first and then modified processor,  but you didnt  do this in the confines of a test (which would be failing by not compiling at first - because interface doesnt exist, and then failing - for the right reasons - when expectation on mock wasnt met  and until method is updated with call ).  The process of doing this is  called "budding off",  perhaps it subtle, but creating your colloborators during writing the test is a more religious way of doing it.  Also, I dont "think" you need "verifiable" on your mock.

Comment: `which would be failing by not compiling at first` - The code that doesnt compile can not be considered a step - because nothing is finished. this is not a religious approach, just a strange one.
Also - you could add a test to the constuctor to assert that it needs an interface before you modify the processor - however, this is not testing the behaviour, but testing the plumbing. the final test harness will catch this if someone refactors the constructor - our tests will no longer compile. So it's a question of how much you value testing itself over developing actual code with a test harness.

Comment: I value testing behaviour and driving this out through having my tests in place. I aim not to write any production code before this is done.  We are not just testing plumbing when changing the constructor you are changing the public api.  If there were multiple tests covering this class a further refactoring step of tests is needed (which could be done using a builder to isolate changes).  I am a bit confused why writing a test first is strange, as - again - you do not do this in your answer.  Perhaps I am reading incorectly and we are saying similar things.  My approach is sound though.